# Entity Framework Core include filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to C# and Entity Framework Core. I have searched a lot for this question but did not found an answer. I have the following three models (I have simplified it):

```
public class Exercise
{
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ExerciseName { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ExerciseClinicalPicture> ExerciseClinicalPicture { get; set; }
}

public class ClinicalPicture
{
    [Key]
    public int ClinicalPictureId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Krankheitsbild")]
    public string ClinicalPictureName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ExerciseClinicalPicture> ExerciseClinicalPicture { get; set; }
}

public class ExerciseClinicalPicture
{
    [Key]
    public int ExerciseClinicalPictureId { get; set; }

    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

    public int ClinicalPictureId { get; set; }

    public ClinicalPicture ClinicalPicture { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to have a query where the result is a collection of all exercises which are associated with a certain clinical picture and the `clinicalPicture` is included.

Something like this:

```
int id = 1;
exercises = _context.Exercise.Where(e => e.ExerciseClinicalPicture.ClinicalPictureId == id)
.Include(m => m.ExerciseClinicalPicture)
.ThenInclude(m => m.ClinicalPicture);
```

This query throws an error because I can not call `ClinicalPictureId` on a collection of `ExerciseClinicalPicture`.

Hope my question is OK like this. It is the first time I ask a question on Stackoverflow.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
exercises = _context.Exercise.Where(e => e.ExerciseClinicalPicture.ClinicalPictureId == id)
```

to this:

```
exercises = _context.Exercise.Where(e => e.ExerciseClinicalPicture.Any(ec => ec.ExerciseId == id))
```

Basically, "Get exercises where any of the exercise clinical pictures on the exercise contains the given exercise ID."
In your models, ExerciseClinicalPicture is a collection. You have to dig into it once more. Your error is that the property doesn't exist because it's a collection.

And this is how you'd query it. Then you can just do your includes as you would normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also tell me the query when I want to filter for a name in the ClinicalPicture?

Comment: _context.Exercise.Where(e => e.ExerciseClinicalPicture.Any(ec => ec.ClinicalPicture.ClinicalPictureName == "Name"))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @TheAnathema this only works if you do not want to retrieve the information from the parent object. Do you know how can I always get the parent object even if the child list does not meet the conditions above ?